# Is there something wrong with Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand, why Ask Ubuntu is like this. out of every 10 to 20 questions only 1 is answered. And the Ubuntu website is advertising it as it's main Q&A web site! Don't you think something is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: *Every what I don't know 10 or maybe 20 questions and only 1 is answered.*  Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: We have a low answering rate (nowhere near "only one in ten questions is answered", though) and we're battling that, but there is nothing *wrong* with AU.

Comment: @FEichinger no I didn't mean to insult anyone or say that you awesome guys are not trying, you are, I meant there should be updates released from these questions, because obviously if a question is not answered by you guys it is probably a bug.

Comment: You didn't make that sentence better readable, maybe try and write two (or even three) sentences instead of that one, that starts with "Every-".

Comment: So, where are you seeing at these questions?  Also, just FYI, we have a [whole chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) dedicated to clearing out old questions.

Comment: @Seth what about the new unanswered ones? I mean not a single question I asked is answered!

Comment: "because obviously if a question is not answered by you guys it is probably a bug." - Incorrect. A question having no answer could have any number of reasons. And *if* it *is* a bug, or looks like one: Comment on it, flag it as off-topic, or post it to the Regulators Room Seth just linked.

Comment: "what about the new unanswered ones?" Patience, my dear. Patience.

Comment: @FEichinger So you think there aren't enough users yet? Also consider that learning what's inside Ubuntu needs a really long long learning curve.

Comment: You know I really love to answer most of the questions but I don't have the knowledge. I really really do, I think we should find a way to fix this, like a guide on how to troubleshoot someones problem, not like the one Ubuntu has posted. Something to compare, oh mine is like that so yours is wrong and it's really easier to find an answer.

Comment: Well, we call that "Search".

Comment: But most of the times, search isn't an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I *really* don't want to sound rude, (I'm not trying to be in any way).

First: We only have the information that the question asker gives us to work with.  So questions that don't include hardware information, version information and aren't descriptive don't usually get answers.  There is very little we can do about that.

The questions on the front page are only questions that have been asked or edited recently, so of course most of the unanswered ones would appear on it.  If you search for `isaccepted:yes` you will get a [list of all accepted/answered questions.](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=isaccepted%3ayes)

[image]

Doing the math from that screenshot, we actually have over 30,000 questions answered here and we're working hard on improving that.

Comment: Yes I understand, so is there any way to simplify the troubleshooting process? lot's of people (including me) don't know how to post specific hardware information. and if they are asked to they can only provide for example what windows used to offer them.

Comment: We actually [have thought about and discussed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5738/44179) that, but I'm afraid the project fell thorugh :/

Comment: wow awesome awesome thing, I wish there was a way we could bring it back.

Comment: Well it isn't *completely* dead yet.  I'll bring it up in chat later and see what the status is.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @Soroosh129 I forgot to reply earlier, sorry, but the project seems pretty dead unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

The site, at the time this answer was written, has 90,000 questions give or take.

The answered rate is 75%.

So the inverse is actually true.

1 in 4 questions is unanswered or abandoned.
That's quite the opposite of 1 in 20 answered.

[Reference](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Comment: Wow, so I guess I was wrong. my bad. You know I didn't mean anything bad, I just see lot's of people questions remains unanswered. And I really love stackexchange websites.

Comment: We understand what you mean :)

Comment: @Soroosh129 Well, the unanswered questions are displayed on the front page a disproportionately large amount of the time. This is so they get seen and answered. Perhaps that why it seemed to you that most were unanswered.

Comment: yes but also lot's of questions get deleted.

Comment: Combining this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15712/how-do-i-run-a-script-command-on-suspend with the ability to use modprobe answers one of your unanswered questions @Soroosh129 . demonstrating the power of search for "run script on suspend"

Comment: I see, but getting Ubuntu to run in a daily basis for normal people that are so busy that can't dedicate any time to their operating system needs some tools. Including some automatic troubleshooters. I have friends that complain about Ubuntu, they don't see awesome thing that I see, they want their job done, they close their laptop, they come back and expect to see their desktop but they see a black screen and they have to restart. It makes them frustrated, makes them hate the very foundations of linux. That I can't see, I am set in a way to fix thisl

Comment: Okay...discussions go in chat.  Not on meta.  If you have a question about the auto-troubleshooter project, that should be a separate meta question.  The question that was asked is answered here.  You only need 20 rep to talk there, so you could craft an answer to your unanswered question with the one I already linked.  I'm sure that would get you over the 20 point hump.

Comment: Soooo, which one should I accept? :D

Comment: Either one.  They're equally valid.

Comment: You know you have enough up votes, I'm going to the other one. no hard feelings :D

Comment: @Soroosh129 If you're not satisfied with the answers here, you shouldn't accept any. And since this is a [meta-tag:discussion] question on meta, accepting is fine but not expected. Also nobody gains/loses reputation here on Meta.AU, that's just for [the main site](http://askubuntu.com). Back-and-forth discussion is also much more tolerated on meta than main as the purpose of meta is *not just* to ask and answer questions based on facts. You should still consider expanding your question (as on main), and if you have a different topic about the site, ask separately. But your comments are fine.

Comment: ok, good to know the rules. thank you.